# Redraw an Image in a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

Im drawing an image into a canvas. When I click a button, the code below is executed:

```
function somefunction(newImage){
    var myid_signature = document.getElementById("cnv");    
    var myid_ctx_signature= myid_signature.getContext('2d');
    var myid_signature_image  = new Image();                    
    myid_signature_image.src = newImage

    if (myid_signature_image.complete){
        myid_ctx_signature.drawImage(myid_signature_image,0,0,  myid_signature_image.width,  myid_signature_image.height, 0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height);                                     
    }else{
        myid_signature_image.onload = function () {                            
            myid_ctx_signature.drawImage( myid_signature_image,0,0,  myid_signature_image.width,  myid_signature_image.height, 0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height);
        };                                              
    }
}
```

myid_signature_image source is changing verytime. The code works only for the first time , but the second time I click the button, it doesnt update the canvas. How will I redraw an image in a canvas?

Comment: The second one? What do you mean?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the ``sample.png`` is modified between ``.drawImage`` calls. Are you sure browser does not take the image from the cache thus you see no difference?

Comment: No it will update the canvas, but you have to clear the canvas before Drawing. ```myid_ctx_signature.clearRect(0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height);```

Comment: @tiblu --> I updated my post for clarification. The image path and filename is changing everytime...

Comment: @Moussawi7 --> I tried what you said but it only clears the canvas but doesnt load the image after clearing.

Comment: Check if the images are being found in the network tab

Comment: I used  code from now deleted answer - http://jsfiddle.net/e3to5rmq/
Seems it should work fine as long as cache is busted (by params or setting proper headers in server) and files are found. So check for these 2 to be true.

Comment: @Yahweh, In fact i tried it on laptop and everything gonna fine, please create a fiddle file, and let us check the issue, may you want to try     ```myid_signature_image.onload = function () {/*COde*/};``` and execute the code inside it.

Comment: Try setting src *last* (after onload is defined). In IE this may matter. Also, no need to use full signature for drawImage (based on the above example), just use image and position. Also add an onerror handler and console.log if you should end up in there...